# sethostname identifier not found error

Tags: c, windows, winapi, network-programming, udp

I want to set the name of my local host. I am using sethostname() function but I get an error as follows:

```
error C3861: 'sethostname': identifier not found.
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
WSADATA wsa;
///Initialise winsock///
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
   {
      //Socket Initialization Failed///
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
 char setname[128]="Ayesha-PC";
 sethostname(setname, sizeof (setname));
```

Comment: Are you sure `sethostname` exists on desktop winsock?  I can see it [documented for WinCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450918.aspx) but it doesn't appear in the [list of desktop winsock2 functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741394(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I think that's the issue. Is there any other function for desktop winsock that can set host name? :(

Comment: @AyeshaHassan what your host name and how its register on your NAT may be diffrent...Suppose you have two computers with same name behind single NAT(your connection) then do you think they can share same name? No in NAT table they are register with some other name e.g.  first `Ayesha-PC-1`  second `Ayesha-PC-2`. using your IP you can retire your hostname read about [getaddrinfo function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx)  and other related functions to retrieve name . You need `IP` to `name` translate function a DNS question..a interesting Q+1.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan Ok have a look on this: [gethostbyaddr function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738521(v=vs.85).aspx) there is a C Code too for windows platform.

Comment: and that is called Official name, `printf("\tOfficial name: %s\n", remoteHost->h_name);` in the linked code. Now run that code input your IP then ..it will output a name(that is official)..then run your code and input to your code that official name instead of what you where earlier given..

Comment: But I want to change the name of my PC according to my choice. Isn't that possible?

Comment: @AyeshaHassan See two things What is your machine name and what is your user name(your OS login id, window login) can be different on your system for example my account name on my Linux System is "grijesh" Where are my `hostname` is "Grijesh-nms-94" (*in Linux we have command `hostname` to know it and system in local NAT table registers with this name*). the name `"Grijesh-nms-94"` I given at the time of my Linux OS installation. On windows you can you change your machine name I don't know but still you have to run that code(or if any available window command) to know registered Official name.

Comment: @AyeshaHassan I guess it should be possible on Window I am not windows user [But this link may be helpful to you](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Registered-Name-on-a-Windows-PC) Good Luck!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows uses it's own mechanism for setting the host name. The function you use is either [`SetComputerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`SetComputerNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Changes take effect on the next reboot. You can request a reboot using [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You'll need to have administrator privileges to invoke these routines, the reason for the reboot requirement is because a lot of windows sub systems will not check the hostname after starting up and will keep using the old name (this is similar in Linux); It may have consequences for `DNS` in domains as well.